# FlowPlayer не работает в Opera и InternetExplorer

Tags: opera, internet-explorer, flash-player

День добрый, столкнулся с проблемой что Opera не хочет отображать видео на сайте пример тому: _obyava.com/demo
На главной странице видео ролик находиться с лева от Онлайн-поддержки. 
В браузерах на "WebKit" все работает на ура.
Такая-же проблема и в InternetExplorer. Он отображает что-то ввиде подсказки к плееру. "Press F to FullScreen..." и т.п...

Comment: Опера молодец. В ней есть ещё замечательная функция "загружать плагины только по запросу". Пользователь, вообще-то, не обязан поглощать все ролики на странице.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поставил плеер Uppod и все заработало. Всем спасибо, все свободны.